# Which library for embeding external font into website?

Tags: javascript, fonts, joomla, mootools

I would like to use external font which is not in google fonts library, so, I need to load it as javascript. Which library is the best.

I am running Joomla and Mootools if it helps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/
```

Upload your font and use it ! :)

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't have to be in the Google Fonts library for you to be able to use it with CSS fonts. First, declare an `@font-face`. For example:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Symbola;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Symbola'), url('/misc/static/Symbola605.ttf/font/truetype') format('truetype');
}
```

Then, use the `font-family` that you specified in that block for any elements you wish to use the font in. This is a far superior alternatives to Flash-based 'text replacement' libraries, that are inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following:

- sIFR: http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/sifr
- Cufon: http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/ (as mentioned by Dawid)
- Fontsquirrel: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

If possible go with fontsquirrel. You'll need to own the fonts tough, because they'll be free to download. If that's not an option give Cufon a try. I don't recommend sIFR. It's given me way more hassles than anything else and it's performance killer.

Cheers
tj

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you use **@font-face**, not cufon, sifr or any image-replacement techniques.
I used both cufon and sifr, they can't hold a candle to @font-face.
They depend on javascript/flash, they add clutter to your markup while font-face depends only on css rule.
Font-face technique leaves the text selectable and you can style it any way you want like any other text.
It doesn't affect your performance either.

That said, cufon / sifr do have some special effect like gradients/shadows that should work cross-browser.

But to me, they are not worth the hassle.